# Error looking for "loading" state when upgrading to pre4 with old router

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

## Problem

After upgrading to the newest ember.js I get this error:

`Uncaught Error: assertion failed: Could not find state for path: "loading"`

Looking at the framework code, it seems that ember wants to route to a 'loading' route until the ember data promises return.  I didn't see any documentation about a 'loading' route, so just tried adding one like this:

```
loading: Ember.Route.extend({
}),
```

which results in the error:

`Uncaught Error: assertion failed: Loading state should not be a route`

## Clues

- Running build from master (commit `693c8185fbda70df523bb60d21f3dc6d9d94b018`)
- Using the old router build (`ember-old-router.js`) so I can upgrade without rewriting my router
- Error only happens when I navigate directly to the URL.  It does not happen when I route from a sibling route.

## Question

Should I be defining a loading route somewhere?  If so, what is the syntax?  If not, how can I prevent this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a curious issue, because I thought `Ember.StateManager`/`Ember.State` were no longer used, but it seems like you're using them somewhere.

*Why is this?*

Nevertheless, by declaring `loading` as an `Ember.State`, it should at least fix your problem, but unless I'm horribly mistaken, you should be moving well away from `Ember.State` in favour of the new router.

`loading: Ember.State.extend();`

Comment: Your answer fixed the error...thanks!  FWIW, I'm using the `ember-old-router.js` to break my upgrade into smaller steps.  First I will fix my action helpers, data adapter, etc.  Then I will re-write my router as a separate step.